# Unable to use a crt certificate with itfoxtec saml2

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am trying to get a web application set up with itfoxtec saml2 and my sso provider (Duo) only provides a crt certificate (not a pfx).

I tried to use it without having a certificate and on a secure page's request, I am redirected to Duo's authentication, but on the redirect back, I receive the following error:

```
InvalidSignatureException: Signature is invalid.
```

I have tried to add the certificate using the below code in my Program.cs:

```
// snip
saml2Configuration.SigningCertificate = CertificateUtil.Load(builder.Environment.MapToPhysicalFilePath(configuration["Saml2:SigningCertificateFile"]));

saml2Configuration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
saml2Configuration.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

// snip
```

When I do this, I get the following when I try to access a secure page:

```
ArgumentException: No RSA Private Key present in Signing Certificate or missing private key read credentials.
```

Thank you for any insight into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the certificate received from the IdP to the `SignatureValidationCertificates` collection: https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L38

And not set it as your `SigningCertificate`.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thanks so much.  And thanks from everyone for developing this package and being so responsive on SO.